# Javascript: false if expression continues execution of if scoped code

Tags: javascript

I am experiencing some of the weirdest behavior of Javascript.

Even though the expression in the `if` statement evaluates to `false`, my code inside the `if block` keeps executing.

Here is the code snippet:

```
if (view.leftCols !== null) {
    var leftCols = view.leftCols.split(',');

    for (var lc = 0; lc < leftCols.length; lc++) {
        var lcv = leftCols[lc].split(':');
        var lcol = lcv[0];

        Array.add(allCols, lcol);

        try {
            var lwidth = lcv[1] - MyWorkGrid.getColWidth(lcol);

            if (lcol === 'Edit') {
                if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 8) {
                    lwidth = 23;
                }
            }

            // this if statement fails.
            if (lwidth > 0) {
                grid.SetWidth(lcol, lwidth);
            }
        } catch (e) {
        }

         grid.MoveCol(lcol, 0, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Here is my Firebug screenshot:

[image: Firebug]

Any ideas?

Comment: What you say happens really cannot happen, so you'd better post the code. That screenshot is illegible.

Comment: Unreadable screenshot, pls. provide the code AND the current values of the variables being used in the "if". Oh, and by the way, it's *always* the human in front of the computer, I find out for myself again and again :)

Comment: just an assumption, but maybe firebug has cached an older version of the script and what you see in it when you're doing step by step execution is not what's actually being executed...

Comment: Which of the many "if" statements are causing the problem?

Comment: @FluffyKitten: from the FireBug screenshot, obviously the last one. It seems that the Watch for `lwidth` shows `0`, but the code inside the statement is apparently executed.

Comment: @Groo: The breakpoint isn't inside the `if`, but Moon has apparently single-stepped over it and the line is now highlighted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Good point. Let me actually set the breakpoint inside the if and see if I can reach there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Despite the line being highlighted in Firebug, are you sure it's *really* being executed? I've seen this behavior in Firebug (and early versions of the Chrome debugger) where they would sometimes highlight a line of code as though they'd stepped to it, without that line actually getting executed.

So I'd insert something unambiguous (like a `console.log("lwidth = " + lwidth);` into the `if` statement's body to see if it *really* executes. The answer may be that Firebug is just highlighting/showing that line as the current one incorrectly without the code thereon actually being run.

Comment: You are correct. If I set the breakpoint inside the if statement. It is never reached when `lwidth <= 0` ... God help Firebug!

Comment: @Moon: I'm glad that was it. If you have a simple test case that replicates the problem, probably worth [reporting it](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list). If I'd done so when I saw it a couple of years ago (I haven't used Firebug for a while), maybe you wouldn't have run into it now. (Sorry about that.) :-)

Comment: I retain from my youth a strong distrust of debuggers; my youth was long ago and they pretty much never worked, at least not when there was something "interesting" to debug.  I'm still a `console.log()` fan (even though its async behavior is disquieting).

Answer (score -1):

It's only the last line of the code block which is being highlighted. As noted in the accepted answer above the highlighted line is NOT actually executed.

```
 1*   var a=0;b=0;c=0;
 2*   if( false ){
 3>       a++;
 4>       b++;
 5*       c++;
 6>   }
 7>
 8*   console.log( a+b+c ); // will output 0;
```

Firebug will step on lines 1 and 2 and then will step to line 5 but will not increment variables a,b or c, they will all remain at 0.

(p.s. can't comment.. so posting answer with extra detail for 2013 )

Comment: What?!! I have no idea why did you say what you said!

Comment: Sorry.. it was a year later but I had thought others might have bumped into the same strange fireBug behavior. I had.. and the accepted answer helped me realize the code wasn't actually being executed.. just highlighted.  It was my first posting and stackoverflow wouldn't let me comment so that's probably what confused you.